# Icons in near wallet

Tags: nearprotocol, near, nearprotocol-validator

Does anyone know where in the documentation you can see what each of the icons that appear in the transactions of the near wallet and the testnet wallet mean? I attach an image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The icons are just visual representation of the actions the wallet has undertaken. Note that the icons in use by the explorer are different than the ones that could be seen in the in the wallet.

On the picture you have provided are seen 2 icons the

- yellow representing "Contract Deployed"
- the grey one representing "Called Method" (the shape of it represents <> generally associated with "code")

few other icons can be seen representing actions such as
transfer, key-added, key-deleted, batch-transaction